# iOS error: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x726f635f)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, exc-bad-access

I got this problem in developing my first iOS app that manage a DB. 
I have a DB with scores of the game and want to show them in a table, when (at runtime) I enter the scoreView app crash with this error:

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x726f635f)
```

Here is the code that Xcode show me as responsible of this problem:

```
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql , -1, &select_statement, NULL)
    == SQLITE_OK) {
                    while (sqlite3_step(select_statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
                        // read from DB
                        NSString *rank = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 0)];
                        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 1)];
                        NSString *score = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 2)];
                        NSString *date = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 3)];

                        // I insert all the string in a dictionary
                        NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:rank,@"Rank",name,@"Name",score,"Score",date,@"Date",nil];
                        [tempList addObject:dictionary];
                    }

                self.list = tempList;
                sqlite3_finalize(select_statement);
}
```

The error is in the line:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:rank,@"Rank",name,@"Name",score,"Score",date,@"Date",nil];
```

After reading from DB I'm trying to save all strings in a dictionary and at the end all dictionaries (in tempList) go into "list", an array to show scores in the table. 
I read on the internet that this problem may be caused by different threads accessing the same object but I don't know how to solve it. 
I was following a tutorial for use DB in iOS app and of course this problem wasn't there.
If someone can help me I'll very appreciate, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
... score, "Score" ...
```

should read:

```
... score, @"Score" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, I didn't see the line where you initialized your mutable array tempList before you trying to add an object.

```
NSMutableArray* tempList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

And you have syntax error, and `NSDictionary` can't be initialized as `NSMutableDictionary`

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:rank,@"Rank",name,@"Name",score,@"Score",date,@"Date",nil];
[tempList addObject:dictionary];
```

And for all string:

```
NSString *score = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help too. I changed only the syntax error and it's all ok! Are you sure that NSDictionary can't be initialized as NSMutableDictionary? Because I saw this in the tutorial and Xcode don't gives any error.